# Using tsl-mastodon-api in angular project: Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, mastodon

I have an angular 17 project that uses the [tsl-mastodon-api](https://github.com/typescriptlibs/tsl-mastodon-api) (0.4.1) as a dependency.
tsconfig says `"target": "ES2022"` but I still get:

> ✘ [ERROR] Top-level await is not available in the configured target
> environment ("chrome119.0", "edge119.0", "firefox115.0", "ios16.0",
> "safari16.0" + 7 overrides)
>
> ```
> node_modules/tsl-mastodon-api/lib/Bridge.js:21:5:
>   21 │     (await import('node-fetch')).default);
> ```

Not sure what to do as the `await` is part of the library and anyway my build target should support it.